# golang ssh quiet mode

Tags: go, ssh

In golang ssh(golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) package how to force the ssh command to use quiet mode i.e. simulate 'ssh -q'

I looked at Config and ClientConfig structures as well as tried searching for 'quiet' or options in the documentation(https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) but can't find anything.

Comment: what is the `ssh_util` package? What is it printing out?

Comment: @JimB Thanks for looking into my Qs. I updated the ssh package in my Qs I am using golang.org/x/crypto/ssh https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh

Comment: quiet mode is a feature of the OpenSSH `ssh` command-line utility. It's not a feature of the SSH protocol per se. Golang ssh looks like it's an ssh implementation, rather than a wrapper around the command-line utility. Is golang outputting a particular message that you're trying to suppress? Could you [edit] your question to show the relevant code from your program and the messages that you're trying to suppress?

Comment: @DeepakOjha: like Kenster points out, the `crypto/ssh` package doesn't print anything by itself, so  there is no "quiet" mode to simulate. Please create a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @Kenster and JimB Thanks for your replies. You both nailed it, crypto/ssh doesn't print anything by itself. My concern was not valid. I used the command in ssh CLI and was worried about some extra messages but when using crypto/ssh don't see them. I will summarize this with example for benefit of others.

Answer (score 1):

Credits: Thanks to @JimB and @Kenster for nailing this.

Quiet mode is not required for (golang.org/x/crypto/ssh). Extra messages that you would usually see when using a ssh CLI won't appear when using (golang.org/x/crypto/ssh). Here is an example of extra messages:

sshpass -ppassword ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 10.10.10.10 'ls  | wc -l'

Warning: Permanently added '10.10.10.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

19

sshpass -ppassword ssh -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 10.10.10.10 'ls  | wc -l'

19